# Getting data validation to work with PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, phpspreadsheet

I'm using laravel and I need to convert my array into a string so that I can add it to the phpSpreadsheet validation. So that when I download an excel spreadsheet
I can select a list of products. The problem I'm having is that I can't get it to be the format that is needed.
Here is the documentation [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell)

The correct format is

```
$validation->setFormula1('"Item A,Item B,Item C"');
```

Here is my code

```
public function generate()
{

    $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet;

    $validation = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B5')->getDataValidation();
    $validation->setType( DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
    $validation->setErrorStyle( DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
    $validation->setAllowBlank(false);
    $validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
    $validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
    $validation->setShowDropDown(true);
    $validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
    $validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
    $validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
    $validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');

    $products = Product::all();
    $product_list = [];

    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        $product_name = $product->name;
        array_push($product_list, $product_name);
    }

    $validation->setFormula1($product_list);
}
```

I tried a `json_encode()`, but it seems that excel doesn't like that.

Comment: is `$agency_name` in `$validation->setFormula1($agency_name);` a typo? Shouldn't it be `$validation->setFormula1($product_list);`?

Comment: yes it was a typo. Sorry about that. I've edited my question

Comment: The problem is that you are passing an array to setFormula1 method, it accepts and string, and the list of values must be internally quoted. Ex. $validation->setFormula1('"val1, val2, valN"'); Pay attention, the php string is quoted by single and the list for values is quoted by double.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation `$product_list` should be a comma delimited string not an array.

```
$products = Product::all();
$product_list = '';

foreach($products as $product) {
    $product_name = $product->name;
    $product_list .= '"' . $product_name . '",';
}

$validation->setFormula1(rtrim($product_list,','));
```

Answer (score -1):

$validation4->setFormula1(implode(','), $product_list);

must be string right or formula range cell like =$A;

some value can find when you try make data validation list type on excel, you use that on your program.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).